# Running a lot of jobs with sun grid engine

Tags: cluster-computing, grid-computing, sungridengine

I want to run a very large number (~30000) of jobs with Sun Grid Engine.

I can theoretically, perform 30000 times the "qsub" command to submit jobs. However, I am afraid that will be too much.

Is there a better way to do it? (i.e. from a file)
Or otherwise, do you think it will work nonetheless?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like at least some versions of SGE support Array Jobs, which sounds like what you want.

Look at "-t" and "-tc" options in the documentation for qsub located [here](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/nonav/source/browse/~checkout~/gridengine/doc/htmlman/manuals.html?content-type=text/html).

Check out [this](https://wiki.duke.edu/display/SCSC/SGE+Array+Jobs) link too, maybe it will be helpful.